# Can't Hide my Record Selectors from subform

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

Can you please help me identify why still my Record Selectors are not hiding even after I change the record selectors value to "No" from Form property?

[image]

I also tried to do this using VBA. code is as below.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.RecordSelectors = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not replicate this, and suspect you are addressing the form, not the subform?

Anyway, open the *subform* - alone, as a form - in designview, and set the property to False. Then save and close the form.

When you open the main form, the subform will have no record selectors.